# Merge/Update records from the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I have two recordsets from a single table:

```
SELECT * FROM userconfig WHERE userid = 'user1'
```

AND

```
SELECT * FROM userconfig WHERE userid = 'user2'
```

I would like to update or merge (whatever is easier) one column from a specific user's recordset into the recordset of the other user. IE: **user1** has a column `configvalue` whose values I want to insert into **user2's** `configvalue` column. I need both columns to have the same value. What is the simplest way to achieve this?

Comment: some sample data would help your cause. also post your attempt

Comment: What do you mean by recordset? Are you saying you have two `select` statements that provide output? Are you looking to `union` the results?

Comment: You want two identical record sets?

Comment: `SELECT configkey FROM userconfig WHERE userid = 'user1'` and `SELECT configkey FROM userconfig WHERE userid = 'user2'` have different values in the `configvalue` column. I need them to match. Why the downvote?

Comment: a slightly more generic way of doing it would be to do a literal `merge` statement

Comment: Very unclear.   Do you want to change the data in the table, or merge the results of two SELECTs?

Comment: I really appriciate the downvotes for such a straight forward question. Try not to overthink this one guys and gals. Two users, **user1** and **user2**. Both users have different values in their `configvalue` column. I would like for **user2** to have the same column values as **user1**. I don't know an easier way to state the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Update 
     user2.userkey = user1.userkey, 
     user2.uservalue = user1.uservalue 
FROM 
     MyTable user2 INNER JOIN MyTable user1 ON user1.YourKey = user2.YourKey
```

The same table, MyTable (replace with your table name).  Join this table back to itself based on the YourKey column (replace YourKey with the column where the join matches).

Then simply assign the alias values of user1 into user2.  Aliases and joining back to the same table is the key.